# QT Library imported in iOS native sdk

Tags: c++, swift, qt, qml

So the plan for this project is to have a QT library that can be used in a native SDK.
We have done a mock library that when imported in a QT App buit into  a xcodeproj works without issues.

The library is static, running lipo -info returns x86_64 arm64.

I used the tutorial from https://alediaferia.com/2014/12/18/a-native-ios-app-with-a-qt-third-party-library/ but got stuck. After a bit of digging I got to the step where linking occurs this is the result:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_pcre2_match_16", referenced from:
      safe_pcre2_match_16(pcre2_real_code_16 const*, unsigned short const*, int, int, int, pcre2_real_match_data_16*, pcre2_real_match_context_16*) in libQt5Core.a(qregularexpression.o)
  "_pcre2_match_context_create_16", referenced from:
      QRegularExpressionPrivate::doMatch(QString const&, int, int, int, QRegularExpression::MatchType, QFlags<QRegularExpression::MatchOption>, QRegularExpressionPrivate::CheckSubjectStringOption, QRegularExpressionMatchPrivate const*) const in libQt5Core.a(qregularexpression.o)
  "_pcre2_jit_stack_assign_16", referenced from:
      QRegularExpressionPrivate::doMatch(QString const&, int, int, int, QRegularExpression::MatchType, QFlags<QRegularExpression::MatchOption>, QRegularExpressionPrivate::CheckSubjectStringOption, QRegularExpressionMatchPrivate const*) const in libQt5Core.a(qregularexpression.o)
  "_pcre2_jit_stack_free_16", referenced from:
      QThreadStorage<QPcreJitStackPointer*>::deleteData(void*) in libQt5Core.a(qregularexpression.o)
  "_pcre2_get_ovector_pointer_16", referenced from:
      QRegularExpressionPrivate::doMatch(QString const&, int, int, int, QRegularExpression::MatchType, QFlags<QRegularExpression::MatchOption>, QRegularExpressionPrivate::CheckSubjectStringOption, QRegularExpressionMatchPrivate const*) const in libQt5Core.a(qregularexpression.o)
  "_pcre2_match_data_free_16", referenced from:
      QRegularExpressionPrivate::doMatch(QString const&, int, int, int, QRegularExpression::MatchType, QFlags<QRegularExpression::MatchOption>, QRegularExpressionPrivate::CheckSubjectStringOption, QRegularExpressionMatchPrivate const*) const in libQt5Core.a(qregularexpression.o)
  "_pcre2_config_16", referenced from:
      QRegularExpressionPrivate::getPatternInfo() in libQt5Core.a(qregularexpression.o)
  "_pcre2_pattern_info_16", referenced from:
      QRegularExpressionPrivate::getPatternInfo() in libQt5Core.a(qregularexpression.o)
      QRegularExpressionPrivate::doMatch(QString const&, int, int, int, QRegularExpression::MatchType, QFlags<QRegularExpression::MatchOption>, QRegularExpressionPrivate::CheckSubjectStringOption, QRegularExpressionMatchPrivate const*) const in libQt5Core.a(qregularexpression.o)
  "_pcre2_jit_compile_16", referenced from:
      QRegularExpressionPrivate::optimizePattern() in libQt5Core.a(qregularexpression.o)
  "_pcre2_match_context_free_16", referenced from:
      QRegularExpressionPrivate::doMatch(QString const&, int, int, int, QRegularExpression::MatchType, QFlags<QRegularExpression::MatchOption>, QRegularExpressionPrivate::CheckSubjectStringOption, QRegularExpressionMatchPrivate const*) const in libQt5Core.a(qregularexpression.o)
  "_pcre2_compile_16", referenced from:
      QRegularExpressionPrivate::compilePattern() in libQt5Core.a(qregularexpression.o)
  "_pcre2_code_free_16", referenced from:
      QRegularExpressionPrivate::~QRegularExpressionPrivate() in libQt5Core.a(qregularexpression.o)
      QRegularExpressionPrivate::compilePattern() in libQt5Core.a(qregularexpression.o)
  "_pcre2_jit_stack_create_16", referenced from:
      safe_pcre2_match_16(pcre2_real_code_16 const*, unsigned short const*, int, int, int, pcre2_real_match_data_16*, pcre2_real_match_context_16*) in libQt5Core.a(qregularexpression.o)
  "_pcre2_match_data_create_from_pattern_16", referenced from:
      QRegularExpressionPrivate::doMatch(QString const&, int, int, int, QRegularExpression::MatchType, QFlags<QRegularExpression::MatchOption>, QRegularExpressionPrivate::CheckSubjectStringOption, QRegularExpressionMatchPrivate const*) const in libQt5Core.a(qregularexpression.o)
  "_uncompress", referenced from:
      qUncompress(unsigned char const*, int) in libQt5Core.a(qbytearray.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[image: The current linker flags]

How the project looks:

[image: The project structure.]

Does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the linking to libqtpcre2

Add

```
-lqtpcre2
```

into your "OTHER LINKER FLAGS" in xcode's "build settings"

Comment: Thank you. That fixed most of the issues. I still have "_uncompress", referenced from:
      qUncompress(unsigned char const*, int) in libQt5Core.a(qbytearray.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 though and that is weird.

Comment: Adding -lz at the end of Other Linker Flags fixed the last issue also. Thank you.